# Why is the union type of two interfaces which extend a generic interface not applicable to that generic interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a simple generic interface `W` and two interface `T` and `N` which extend `W` and add a property `type` which could be used in a tagged union:

```
interface W<V> {
    value: V
}

interface T extends W<string> {
    type: 'text'
}

interface N extends W<number> {
    type: 'number'
}
```

Additionally, i have a type `D`, which is the union of `T` and `N`, and a function `getValue` which expects an argument which conforms to the generic wrapper type and simply returns its wrapped value.

```
type D = T | N

const getValue = <V extends any>(
  wrapper: W<V>
): V => {
    return wrapper.value
}
```

My issue is, that if i create a value with type `D` and pass it to `getValue`, the tsc complains that `the argument of type 'D' is not assignable to parameter of type 'W<string>'`:

```
// typecast necessary because otherwise tsc would determine that d is of type 'T' which is what i don't want
const d: D = { value: 'hallo', type: 'text'} as D

// why is 'D' not an acceptable type for getValue??? Shouldn't the inferred return type simply be 'string | number'?
getValue(d)
```

I tried to type the function `getValue` in such a way that the tsc would be able to infer that the return type would be `string | number` if  pass in a value with the type `D`. I expect the compiler not to complain and to infer that the return type would be `string | number` if i pass the value `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a conditional type !

```
interface W<V> {
    value: V
}

interface T extends W<string> {
    type: 'text'
}

interface N extends W<number> {
    type: 'number'
}

type D = T | N

const getValue = <V extends W<any>>(wrapper: V): V extends W<infer U> ? U : never => {
    return wrapper.value; 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOoB4BqA%20ZBvAWAChlTkA3OAGwFcIAuZTYgX2ONElkRQBVkIAD0ggAJgGc06cWCigA5rkIkyYAJ4AHBsgDkkYTtbsinaPCTIAcgOEQxkjCBoBbAEbQlxMsnVbGOpzdoQyI2ImJfFAARZABeZH4AHytjBAB7EBlkeQgwTGo6OOQsGxEJKTgQNWxsAAoAdyg4DS0oRkwASnbSu3KMUBhoZABVXAB%20EeRGEAhyIdjPFVIoXJooEGRG5taAOkpaCABuZCNwolEIBCo4FeR0zLBkUUYow%20ILq5uUe6ywRl43udLtdbj9HiBGJZATk8gUILVRB1kAB6ZHINIAa2IqOQAD0xsYYfkDrUwEicZjsWj8YTcsS6LUQOS0ZSiDj8UA)